# jquery find closes span within td

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j28mz/)   explains my problem.

Can anyone help how to solve this problem

I made my code something like this

```
$('.chg').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('td span').html('test')
    })
```

Comment: `closest` traverses up the tree ( parents, and parents of parents ) so it will never find the sibling element

Comment: $(this).parent().prev().find('span').html('test')

Answer (score 0):

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) searches the ancestor tree to find a matching element, you case the `span` is within an sibling element.

Either you can find the `span` from the `tr` element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chg').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('tr').find('span').html('test')
    })   
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4L6kz/)

Or you can find the `span` within the previous `td` element

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.chg').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().prev().find('span').html('test')
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gHwJQ/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, it will change your span html value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chg').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        sp=$('.chg').parent().parent();
        sp.find('span').html('test');
    })   
})
```